# background-size fixed not working in mobile chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, background-image

In my site [here](https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/) I used a background image to body with `<body style="background: url(http://www.monsoonmalabar.com/assets/jum1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;">`
It is not showing in mobile chrome browser. I tried below code,

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Still not showing in mobile chrome. Any workaround?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS here. Once you fix your website, this question will be useless to future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have html and css in my question

Comment: Where is the HTML? I only see a very small snippet of CSS. That doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a `background` qualifier, it overrode all preset styles (unless with `!important`).

You can instead, set all the properties of background in your `.bod` class and then just set `background-image` inline like in below, You can add as well add it inline if its supposed to be the same image all along.

```
.bod {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

And inside your body tag:

```
background-image: url([path to your image]);
```

Comment: Now mobile chrome showing a strange image, some time it changes slightly on refresh browser. Not giving proper image, but sometimes it give the correct image

Comment: Can you give more details, like what is the strange image? A screenshot probably should help.

Comment: [here](https://i.ibb.co/ZS0Nt52/Screenshot-20190725-143514.png) is one, and after refresh I got [this](https://i.ibb.co/RPJw7MK/Screenshot-20190725-143527.png)

Comment: I can't login in mobile chrome. But I can login and the image shows perfect in android firefox. Can I see it in mobile chrome?